# HTML Element: get notified when the scrollbar appears

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a div like this:

```
<div id='test' style='overflow:auto'>
...
</div>
```

In JavaScript (no jQuery) how do I know when - as a consequence of the user resizing the browser - the div is showing a horizontal bar or not?

Note: I don't want only to figure if it is showing horizontal bar or not, I want to be notified when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hook the resize of window

```
window.onresize = function(){
 var test = document.getElementById("test");
 if(test.offsetHeight != test.scrollHeight)
    // raise event or call ur method
}
```